# No Persistence provider for EntityManager?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jpa

I'm trying to set up a basic JPA. But I cannot even get the `EntityManger`. What might be wrong with the following configuration?

```
private static final EntityManager emf = Persistence
.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional").createEntityManager();
```

`src/META-INF/persistence.xml` (also tried: `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImp</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Result:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named transactions-optional
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at de.verism.server.database.EMFService.<clinit>(EMFService.java:13)
```

Maven Config:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-eb</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!--
                exclude the legacy javax.transaction:transaction-api
                and replace it with javax.transaction:jta (it
                appears to be the same thing)
            -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Updated config:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is *org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImp* added correctly in your class path?

Comment: Yes it's added by maven config updated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's datanucleus-appengine 2.1.x requires DataNucleus 3.1.x (not 3.2.x). 
You should have jdo-api v3.x (not jdo2-api v2.3.x). 
If using JPA you need "datanucleus-api-jpa" v3.1.x (not "datanucleus-jpa" v1.x).
You also then need "geronimo-jpa-2.0_spec" v1.x (not geronimo-jpa-3.0_spec v1.x).

Yes I think its fair to say that you've utterly [messed up the dependencies](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility) ;-)
then when you've fixed that you use [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2) to set the persistence provider

Comment: who should know it better?

Comment: Thanks, but the error remains using the updated maven config above

Comment: so look at those GAE docs, they tell you all there is to do. And the log does too of course.

Comment: Well if the logs tell me "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named transactions-optional" and my persistence.xml has a "transactions-optional" persistance unit defined, I unfortunately don't know what I could do else...

Comment: it cant find your persistence.xml then (and locations under "src" are not of relevance at RUNTIME, so perhaps state where it is at RUNTIME).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the missing *l* at the provider class

<provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImp**l**</provider>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Look into the META-INF, there are two files named:

- jdoconfig.xml
- persistence.xml

If you are using persistence api, then you can get rid of this error by adding the block comment in the jdoconfig.xml file